# Prove that there exists $M > 0$ such that $||k_n|| \leq M$ for all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let ${(k_n)}^\infty_{n=1}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $lim_{n \to \infty} k_n = c$. Prove that there exists $M > 0$ such that $||k_n|| \leq M$ for all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$.

Can I say $||k_n - c||=0$ because its limit converges? Or it is limited to uniformly convergent?

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence to converge? Can an unbounded sequence converge? This is what is asked of you in this task. Also no you cannot say what you proposed, because it is wrong for nonconstant sequences.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence converges to $c$, so for any $\epsilon > 0$ you can find a natural number $N$ such that all members $k_i$ of the sequence with index $i$ higher than $N$ fulfill $||k_i - c || \leq \epsilon$.

That means that for any fixed $\epsilon$ only finitely many members of the sequence have $||k_n - c|| > \epsilon$.

You can pick the maximal value $M_N$ of this distance for all members with index smaller than $N$, as there are only finitely many. Now pick the maximum between $M_N$ and  $\epsilon$.

Comment: hi, why are you using $k_i$ instead of $k_n$? is there any difference between them?

Comment: no, there is no difference. I just called the index $i$ and said that $i \geq N$ to distinguish